# Getting the URL of second last visited page in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I am able to get the previous page URL, but also I need to get the URL of the second last visited page.

I have used the below code..

```
<script>
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("GetUrl");  

function GetUrl() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;
alert(referrer);

//var x=history.go(-2);
//alert(x);
}
</script>
```

but `history.go(-2)` will directly redirect to the second last visited page, how to get that url?

Comment: I am able to get the previous page URL, but also I need to get the URL of the second last visited page. I have used the below code.. <script> _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("GetUrl"); function GetUrl() { var referrer = document.referrer; alert(referrer); //var x=history.go(-2); //alert(x); } </script> but > history.go(-2) will directly redirect to the second last visited page, how to get that url?

Comment: I am able to get the previous page URL, but also I need to get the URL of the second last visited page. I have used the below code..

Answer (score 1):

In general history is protected by the browser against javascript accessing it except through back and forward functionality.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369829/access-my-entire-browsing-history-via-javascript

So you can not access it.

Comment: If you have JS access to all pages store the URL in a cookie

Comment: Excellent alternative solution! @DannyEngelman

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me..

```
<script>
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("GetUrl");  

function GetUrl() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;
//alert(referrer);
}

function SecondLast(){
var x=history.go(-2);
//alert(x);
}


</script>
<button onclick="SecondLast()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Does it prevent you from redirecting?

Comment: no, but now I can do it on button click..

Comment: In your question you asked that **"how to get that url"**. redirecting in button click was not your requirement